# I don't understand this (size_t)_length return statment

Tags: c, return-value

I am writing an memory allocation replacement API for a class I am in, and there is a function called `my_malloc()` below (with a basic skeleton already outlined from the professor) that returns something that I don't understand.

Can someone please enlighten me on why the `_length` argument has that underscore in the beginning, and why the return statement has `(size_t)` not separate from _length?

```
Addr my_malloc(unsigned int _length) {
  /* This preliminary implementation simply hands the call over the 
     the C standard library! 
     Of course this needs to be replaced by your implementation.
  */
  return malloc((size_t)_length);
}
```

Comment: Well, `_length` is simply a name, an underscore in the beginning looks like a naming convention of function arguments, for human beings, not for compilers. The expression (size_t)_length is a cast. I would suggest you to study C language a bit before implementing the task.

Answer (score 4):

1. Whoever wrote the function thought it would be a good idea to call the name `_length`. It doesn't have any special significance.
2. When you have `(Typename)variablename` in an expression it is called a *cast*.  This code converts `_length` to the type `size_t` before passing it to the `malloc` function.

This is actually redundant because that same conversion happens implicitly when `malloc` is called. (Unless we are in C89 and `malloc` was never declared, but that should be fixed by `#include <stdlib.h>`, not by inserting this cast)

Comment: It makes total sense now that you mentioned casting. I've done that plenty in Java. But for some reason, in all my C++ classes I've taken, we were never required to or even taught about casting. So I just assumed it was something special to Java, and never thought anything more of it. Thanks!

Comment: @UnworthyToast it's something that you should avoid unless there is no other way, because in some situations the compiler would catch an error for you - but only if you didn't write the cast.

Comment: The cast is useful in the following case: range of `unsigned` exceeds `size_t` and compiler warns of the narrowing (rare - never heard of this case).  By casting, the warning is quieted.  In such a cast, prior code should insure `_length <= SIZE_MAX`

Comment: @chux I'd rather turn off that warning than pollute the code with casts... when you keep your code clear it's less likely to make a mistake in the first place anyway, and that warning gives a huge amount of false positives since it's normal to do various value conversions.   Range of `unsigned` exceeding `size_t` seems unlikely, I'd be fairly confident in conjecturing there never has been and never will be such a system

Answer (score 0):

The underscore is just part of the variable name. I can define a variable x as well as _x or x__.

To the second question: that is an explicit type cast from int to size_t.

I recommend you read a little about type casting in C, it's important to understand.